# How to express "dreaming" with other than the whole tone scale?

Tags: piano, scales, improvisation, performing, expression

I am working on a little theater play accompanying a **poetic clown** on piano on the stage. Most of time I improvise to **emphasize his emotional moods**, since there are no words at all.

When the character falls asleep I want to play something that expresses that which follows is (or may be) a **dream**, but being subtle and not so cliché-like as a several octaves **whole tone scale** ascension.

I like [NReilingh's approach](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/4976/12121):

> Chords don't give us feelings, we give chords feelings.

So I am not looking for a magical chord or scale to do this. I understand that it is my job to get into the character feelings and to find how to **express them through my hands** using dynamics, tempo... and even corporal expression. But it would be helpful to know other ways, suggestions, examples... to improve my improvisation background.

Comment: The ballet "Somewhere" from WSS is a dream sequence and most certainly not whole-tone.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Impressive! I was already looking for the film before your comment to get ideas for another emotional mood. It seems to be a good reference ;)

Comment: I think this question is too subjective to keep. However in my head I am hearing a repeating rising pattern of 6 notes of equal length.

Comment: Suspended chords, and Lydian tonalities (though admittedly similar to whole tone)

Comment: Quartal harmony (chords built in fourths) can do it too, but this one tends to sound a bit jazzy or avant garde

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the main reasons that a whole-tone scale works so well to indicate dreaming and rootlessness is that it's a symmetrical structure that divides the octave into equal parts. Multiple notes can therefore work equally well as a "tonic" which kind of means that they're also equally *bad* at being tonic. A symmetrical structure makes it much easier to avoid accidentally rooting the improvisation too much around a single note.

So you might want to explore other symmetric pitch collections. Augmented triads, diminished 7ths, tritones, French augmented sixths, hexatonic scales, octatonic scales, etc.

Comment: Different symmetric scales and french (and german) augmented sixths satisfy my needs : )

Comment: @Rober Good! Just a note however, the German augmented sixth isn't symmetrical and is actually just an enharmonic respelling of a dominant seventh chord. This makes it extremely useful for modulating to distant keys, but it actually can have a strongly directional sound. Still, if it works for your purposes, then it's all for the good!

Answer (score 4):

The style of the impressionist can be very dreamy. Listen to *Le Plus Que Lent* by Debussy, or perhaps *Ondine*. A number of his preludes create this dreamy ambiance too. As far as Ravel goes, *La Valse* does a good job of presenting a foggy, distorted version of the main theme. If I were to summarize these techniques briefly, parallelism and extended tertian harmony (7 9 11 13 etc chords).

As mentioned in the comments, *WSS*'s ballet is a good one, so is *Oklahoma*'s.

Answer (score 3):

High pitched rolled chords played softly (usually with some pedal) are sometimes used for dream-like stuff. I've used things like grouping 5-note arpeggios in 16th notes (so the pattern migrates through time) with a simple bass melody to evoke dreams. Or perhaps I'm really evoking running water.